# Can I do pointer arithmetic on an STL::map::iterator

Tags: c++11, iterator

How to correctly use pointer arithmetics for `stl::map::iterator` ?

In example bellow I create `stl::map` and `stl::map::iterator` and try to access iterator second key by increasing the iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    map <string, string> peoples;

    peoples["paul"] = "friend";
    peoples["galactus"] = "foe";

    map<string, string>::iterator my_iter = ++peoples.begin();

    cout << my_iter->first << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When `++peoples.begin();` is used compilation is OK, but if  `1 + peoples.begin();` is used, error is raised.

Question stands: How to use pointer arithmetics on `stl::map::iterator` ?

And are there any containers with similar difficulties, while I know that with `stl::vector::iterator` you can use pointer arithmetics?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I do pointer arithmetic on an STL::map::iterator

No. You can't do *pointer* arithmetic on iterators, since iterators are (in general) not pointers.

If you take a look at the documentation, you'll find that `map::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator. You'll also find that bidirectional iterators do not support addition operator.

You can find `n`'th successor of an iterator by applying the increment operator `n` times. There are standard algorithms for this as well: `next` and `advance`.

> I know that with `stl::vector::iterator` you can use pointer arithmetics?

`vector::iterator` is a random access iterator. Those support addition operator.

---

PS. The original STL wasn't in a namespace, and the standard library is in the namespace `std`; not `stl`.

Comment: So how cpp translates this ++ for the stl::map::iterator ? , it is number that's added in the end, isn't it ?

Comment: @CaféVampire what number is added in the end of what?

Comment: no that's misunderstanding. I am asking how '++' is finally(IN THE END of the compiling process) translated inside cpp. What I was suggesting is, that '++' must result in a number that increases the value of the iterator.

Comment: @CaféVampire I see. Why do you think that ++ must result in a number?

Comment: @CaféVampire: The iterator is probably a class that wraps a pointer to a datastructure.  The `++` operator on that iterator will use the datastructure to find the thing to change the pointer to. There's no numbers involved.